# Can't connect to EC2 Windows machine from Mac

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've tried using Parallels, RDP, and rDesktop. Nothing works. The machine is in a VPC with only private DNS and IP. Other users on the network can get to this box just fine from their mac machines(Yosemite). Wondering if anyone's come across any weird configs that might cause this?

Comment: Silly question but do you actually have a route to the machine? What does ping/traceroute tell you?

Comment: Are you using the same version of Microsoft Remote Desktop as the people who CAN access the instance? Windows 2012 R2 requires the newer version (with the red icon).